# Countsort "core dumped" error

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, count

I'm trying to implement a count sort algorithm in c but I'm getting this `"core dumped"` compiler message. Does anyone know where my mistake is?

I need to sort an array filled with numbers from an external file.

MY CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "arrayio.h"

int MAX_LAENGE = 1000;
int MAX_VALUE = 100;
void count_sort_calculate_counts(int input_array[], int len, int count_array[]) 
{  
    count_array = (int*)calloc(MAX_VALUE, sizeof(int));

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE; i++)
    {
        count_array[i] = 0;
    }

    for(int j = 0; j <= len; j++)
    {
        count_array[input_array[j]] = count_array[input_array[j]] +1;
    }
}

void count_sort_write_output_array(int output_array[], int len, int count_array[]) 
{
    int k = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < count_array[i]; j++)
        {
        output_array[k] = i;
        k = k + 1;
        }   
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc < 2){
        printf("Aufruf: %s <Dateiname>\n", argv[0]);
        printf("Beispiel: %s zahlen.txt\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    char *filename = argv[1];

    int input_array[MAX_LAENGE];
    int len = read_array_from_file(input_array, MAX_LAENGE, filename);

    printf("Unsortiertes Array:");
    print_array(input_array, len);

    int count_array[MAX_VALUE];
    int output_array[MAX_LAENGE];

    count_sort_calculate_counts(input_array, len, output_array);
    count_sort_write_output_array(output_array, len, count_array);
    printf("Sortiertes Array:");
    print_array(output_array, len);

    free(count_array);
    return 0;
}
```

I thought about it for days but I can't solve it.

Comment: `for(int j = 0; j <= len; j++)` => `for(int j = 0; j < len; j++)` else your last iteration reads in the unknown...

Comment: Similarly `calloc(MAX_VALUE, sizeof(int));` should be `calloc(MAX_VALUE + 1, sizeof(int));` to allow `count_array` to be indexed by `MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: already did that but it changed nothing :/

Comment: please post the contents of `arrayio.h`

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`,  In general, when notifying the user of a command line parameter missing, should output a `USAGE` message to `stderr`, similiar to: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s  <parm1>\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: when sorting a file's contents, the best approach is to use `mmap` on the file. Then use something like `qsort()`  or `mergesort()` or similiar to perform the sorting.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, why do you need to allocate memory dynamically?

```
count_array = (int*)calloc(MAX_VALUE, sizeof(int));
```

You only need to allocate memory dynamically if you don't have an idea how much memory is required. Thats the case when you'd use `calloc()` and `malloc()` primarily.

In `main()` function,

```
int count_array[MAX_VALUE];
```

This has already allocated memory (Size = `MAX_VALUE` x size of `int`) for `count_array` compile-time. So, you can get rid of the code which involves `calloc()`.

If you want to initialize all array contents to `0`, then you can use:

```
int count_array[MAX_VALUE] = {0};
```

Secondly, there is an array going out of bounds:

```
for(int j = 0; j <= len; j++)
```

Change it to

```
for(int j = 0; j < len; j++)
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `int count_array[MAX_VALUE + 1];` to allow indexing by `MAX_VALUE`?

Comment: @WeatherVane: Might be, to be honest I haven't looked at that with the perspective you just presented. I almost thought it over thrice if `calloc` is needed, and I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I presume that `MAX_VALUE` is the maximum value expected. The array also needs to be initialised to `0` with `int count_array[MAX_VALUE + 1] =  { 0 };` to perform the same way as `calloc`.

Comment: *This has already allocated memory (Size = MAX_VALUE x size of int) for `count_array` statically.* Using "statically" here could be confusing. `static` is a C keyword that effects how memory is allocated, especially for a local variable such as `count_array` in the posted code. As coded `count_array` exists as long as the `main` function is running, and should multiple `main` functions be running in a multithreaded process, each would have its own copy of `count_array`. `static count_array` means only *one* copy would exist for the life of the program, shared by all copies of `main`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Agreed. Changed it to as simple as 'compile-time'. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this loop:

```
for(int j = 0; j <= len; j++)
{
    count_array[input_array[j]] = count_array[input_array[j]] +1;
}
```

goes 1 `int` too far so reads `input_array[j]` out of `input_array` bounds. Reading one more rarely triggers a crash, but the value is completely random & possibly very high so `count_array[input_array[j]]` accesses a very far address, *very much* out of bounds, hence the crash.

fix proposal (& small simplification):

```
for(int j = 0; j < len; j++)
{
    count_array[input_array[j]] ++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when the code is going to change where a pointer, in the calling function, is pointing via some activity in a called function, then the pointer to the called function must be passed as the address of the pointer.

Similar to:

in function: `main()`

```
int *output_array = NULL;

count_sort_calculate_counts(input_array, len, &output_array);
```

in function: `count_sort_calculate_counts()`

```
void count_sort_calculate_counts(int input_array[], int len, int **count_array)


*count_array = calloc(MAX_VALUE, sizeof(int));
if( !(*count_array) )
{
    // handle error then exit program
}
```

this code block:

```
for(int j = 0; j <= len; j++)
{
    count_array[input_array[j]] = count_array[input_array[j]] +1;
}
```

can be greatly simplified to:

```
for(int j = 0; j <= len; j++)
{
    (*count_array)[input_array[j]] += 1;
}
```